# SQL - Continuous Integration (Data)

Tags: sql, validation, continuous-integration

This is a general question and probably there are some solutions already. Most of the things I have found are related to database development, deployment, etc..

I am looking for a process that runs daily and performs some checks against some tables of a database. The data loaded in these tables is loaded by a lot of users, but the idea is that defining some rules, the process will detect "wrong" values loaded by the user.

I know this is a very open question, but do you know if this possible with some tools: Jenkins, DBGhost, etc...?

Thank you,

Kat

Comment: Maybe try running cron jobs?

Comment: Does the answer help you or were you looking for some more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options. Here's one train of thought.

Create a table called data_audit with fields like so:

- audit_datetime
- table
- field
- wrong_value
- rule_violated
- issue_description

Create stored procedures/functions that can detect wrong values and store the data into this audit table.

Depending on your database, you can run the stored procedure upon schedule. For example, if you have SQL Server, you can run the job using SQL Agent. Once the job is finished, you can run another job that finds `count(*)` from audit table for today's date. If count was higher than zero, use Database Mail feature to email relevant people to take action.

If you have a database like MySQL or PostgreSQL, write a short program in a language of your choice (PHP/Python/.NET/whatever) to execute the stored procedure, then do count(*) and then email if count was higher than zero. You can run this program using either cron on Linux or Linux-like systems or Task Scheduler in Windows.

You could use tools like Jenkins to schedule such activity. Task Scheduler/cron are built into your operating system and are easy to use. Additional installation like Jenkins is not necessary. If you already have Jenkins installed, you can certainly piggy-back on it.